# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on sorting an arrayList which is growing evreytime

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, synchronization

**Scenario**

I have a class variable **arraylist** which will get populated from some serviceProvider when I invoke a search and when the max results are reached it will stop receiving the results.

The serviceProvider provides data as chunks of data.

Everytime I get a result set from the serviceProvider, this arrayList gets added with the new set of data provided from the provider.

This is then displayed in my view by passing this arrayList to my templist in my model.

So whenever I get a result set(or a chunk of results), my arrayList gets updated, and then I will clear my tempList in the model and add the new set arrayList to tempList and then do a rePaint of the list.

I have given the user a feature to sort the list while search is in progress, but this actually creates my problem.

---

**Problem**

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java/util/Collections.sort(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/Comparator;)V (:0:59)
        at com/test/utility/Utility.sortList(ILjava/util/List;)V (Utility.java:517:175)
        at com/test/model/contentdiscovery/SearchModel.SortSearchResults()V (SearchModel.java:701:154)
```

So what was happening was, while the search was in progress, I did a Sort A-Z on the list and then I did a Sort Z-A on the list, the list is getting updated while this was being done.

So what I was doing in the code:

```
SortSearchResults()
{
    Utility.sortList(sort_A_Z, arrayList);  
}
```

Which called

```
Collections.sort(arrayList, new TitleComparatorAtoZUI());
```

Then when I change the sort option to Sort Z-A

```
SortSearchResults()
{
    Utility.sortList(sort_Z_A, arrayList); 
}
```

Which called

```
Collections.sort(arrayList, new TitleComparatorZtoAUI());
```

But the arrayList in each step may be getting added with more elements.

---

**Question**

How to solve this problem? Please advise.
I have tried synchronizing both the methods `Utility.sortList` and `SearchModel.SortSearchResults()`.  It still created the problem.

So I always keep adding the object to arrayList, but my view is then filtering out this arrayList to its tempList(by clearing and adding it again everytime we get a new result set) .

So when we do a sort, the arrayList is supplied for sorting, and when it is done, we will again filter out the sorted arrayList to tempList(by clearing and adding it again).

Comment: Could you explain why is sorting causing the exception?

Comment: What I am thinking is that the arrayList is getting updated and if the sorting takes some time, can it result in this.

Comment: Updating is adding new values to end of arrayList or ?

Comment: Updating is adding new values to end of arrayList.. and then it updated the tempList.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the best way to solve it is simply to separate View from the Model - do not work/modify the same copy of the list. So, your source of truth is the Model and the view will get a copy every time user asks to present it in sorted way. Then the view can sort a local copy without affecting the model. If you want to be 100% in sync than you can implement a callback to be called in the end of chunk update of the list you keep in the Model. Then the view will retrieve a newly updated list, sort it and repopulate the view.

Comment: Effectively, I have two list with me.. The model has the list arrayList and the view has tempList(which is cleared add updated with the arrayList everytime we get a new set added in arrayList)

Comment: That seems a strange choise. If you already have separate lists, then why don't you sort the view specific list instead of the one that does not need the sorting?

Comment: @kiheru, no reason. I think you misinterpreted my idea.

Comment: @Sen, then you should be fine, simply repopulate the temp list every time some related actions are triggered by the view and if the main copy is unavailable (being updated) then set a callback that will retrieve an updated copy to repopulate the tem list once the update is done.

Comment: @aviad Sorry, that was really meant for Sen but I forgot to tag it. Your solution looks like a clean way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization must be on the *same* object. You could use the list as the monitor:

```
synchronized(arrayList) {
     Utility.sortList(sort_A_Z, arrayList);
}

...

synchronized(arrayList) {
    // the code that adds more results
}
```

Alternatively you can create an utility object for that purpose, with methods to lock and free it.

Comment: But should we be synchronizing using a non final object?

Comment: Will I miss any of my data by serializing this.?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the list to not be final? It seems to me that you're treating it as effectively final anyway as you are modifying the existing list.

Answer (score 0):

Do the sorting in the view ie: sort the templist and not the arraylist

Comment: That will not be fine, because, if I have multiple list filters, then the current sorted value in one filter will not be applied if I switch to another filter.

Comment: cant you do it the same way as you did for arrayList?